Existence of directional heat equation without uniform ellipticity
I am asking for references, or for a proof idea on how to show that weak solutions of the following problem exist: search $u$ on a bounded domain $\Omega\times (0,T]$, where $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ with $d>1$ and denote $\partial \Omega$ its boundary (smooth), s.t.
$$\begin{cases}
\displaystyle \partial_{t} u - \partial_{x_1x_1}^2u = f &\quad \text{on } \Omega \times (0,T] \\
u=0 &\quad \text{on }\partial \Omega \times [0,T]\\
u(x,0)=g&\quad \text{on } \Omega 
\end{cases}$$
for given $f,g$, and where $x=(x_1,\dotsc,x_d)\in \Omega$.
The problem resembles the heat equation, but the operator acts only in the $x_1$-direction, so the classic assumptions, like uniform ellipticity and coercivity do not hold. ("Uniformly elliptic" means that the diffusion matrix in front of the gradient-term in the weak heat equation is positive definite or similar.)
Thinking about using a compactness-argument, like used in Galerkin methods, one could try to derive energy estimates without using coercivity. However, I have not managed to do that so far.

You say that the second-order operator acts only in $x$-direction, yet you seem to call the spatial variable in $\Omega$ also $x$, maybe you want to clarify that a bit?

Thank you for the hint, i cleaned up the notation.

As you do not have any sort of coupling in any spatial direction other than $x_1$, what you have here is not actually a time-dependent PDE in $d$-dimensions but a $(d-1)$-parameter family of time-dependent $1$-dimensional PDEs. Specifically for any $\bar{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ define
$$ I_{\bar{x}} := \{x_1 \in \mathbb{R} : (x_1,\bar{x}) \in \Omega \}.$$
Then $u$ solves your original problem if and only if $u(x_1,\bar{x},t) := u_{\bar{x}}(x_1,t)$, where $u_{\bar{x}}$ solves
$$\left\{ \begin{aligned} \partial_t u_{\bar{x}} - \Delta u_{\bar{x}} &= f(\cdot,\bar{x}) &\text{ in }& I_{\bar{x}} \times [0,T] \\ u_{\bar{x}} &= 0 &\text{ in }& \partial I_{\bar{x}} \times[0,T]\\ u_{\bar{x}}(\cdot,0) &= g(\cdot,\bar{x}) &\text{ in }& I_{\bar{x}}\end{aligned}\right.$$
As these are just 1d-heat equations over (collections of) intervals, you can even write down an explicit formula for the solutions, so existence should not be an issue.
Given some regularity of $f$ and $g$ in directions other than $x_1$, you can even try to study the $\bar{x}$-dependence of that system, as the dependence of the heat equation on RHS and initial data is well understood. The only issue here is that the length of the intervals changes depending on $\bar{x}$, which needs to be taken into account.

Thank you for you answer, this was very useful for me. Do you happen to know how the analysis can be adapted to the case where we introduce an additional coupling in the $\bar x$ direction in the first term - e.g. consider $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\partial_t \partial_{yy}^2 u - \partial_{xx}^2  u= f$?

@l'étudiant Then this trick does not work anymore. You could maybe still use it to analyse the operators $\partial^2_x $ and $\partial^2_y $ on $\Omega$ and then do some semi-group theory regarding $(\partial_y^2)^{-1} \partial_x^2$, but I am not entirely sure if your new problem is even well posed.

Thank you very much for your comment.

I think you need enough regularity on $g$ and $f$ in order to define the boundary value. Could you precise the setting that you expect ?
In any case, if you're just asking for existence of a weak solution for the equation without the boundary condition, you can solve a coercive equation like
$$ \partial_t u - \widetilde{\Delta}_\varepsilon u = f,$$
where $\widetilde{\Delta}_\varepsilon = \varepsilon(\Delta - \partial_{x_1x_1}) +\partial_{x_1x_1}$. For $\varepsilon>0$ you have existence (and uniqueness) by standard method to this boundary-value problem, let's call $u_\varepsilon$ this solution. The usual energy estimate gives you at least (if you choose $f$ in $L^2$, say) a bound for $(u_\varepsilon)_\varepsilon$ in $L^\infty_{\text{loc}}(\mathbf{R}_+;L^2(\Omega))$ and since the problem is linear, any weak(-$\star$) cluster point gives you a weak solution, at least in the distributional sense (with test function having compact support inside $\Omega$).

$f,g\in L^2$. I dont understand your answer: at first we assume $\epsilon >0$ (=standard heat equation) and show that $u_\epsilon$ exists. But how does this prove that $u$ exists for the case where $\epsilon =0$?

Thanks to the energy bound, w.l.o.g., you can assume $(u_\varepsilon)$ weakly-$\star$ converge in $L^\infty_{\text{loc}}(\mathbf{R};L^2(\Omega))$ to some $u$. Obviously, $(\varepsilon u_\varepsilon)\varepsilon$ converges now to $0$ for this topology. This type of convergence implies in particular weak convergence in $\mathscr{D}'(\mathbf{R}\times\Omega)$, which commutes with any derivatives. So you can pass to the limit in the $\mathscr{D}'(\mathbf{R}\times\Omega)$ equality
$$ \partial_t u\varepsilon- \widetilde{\Delta}\varepsilon u\varepsilon = f + g\otimes\delta_{t=0}.$$

(I implicitly extended by $0$ for negative times all functions to synthesize the Cauchy problem in one single equation including the initial value).

Could you explain how you have incorporated the initial condition into the equation by adding $g\otimes \delta_{t=0}$?

Omitting the space variable, if you look at an ODE $y' = S$ on $\mathbf{R}+$ with initial condition $y_0$, it's weak formulation is the following $$\int{\mathbf{R}+} y\varphi' =-y_0\varphi(0) -\int{\mathbf{R}+} S\varphi,$$ for test functions $\varphi\in\mathscr{D}(\mathbf{R}+)$. You can then check that this formulation is perfectly equivalent to the equality $\underline{y}'=\underline{S}+ y_0 \delta_0$ in $\mathscr{D}'(\mathbf{R})$, where the underline denotes the extension by $0$ for negative times. Adding the space variable is completely similar.

As I guess you speak french you can also check page 13 of this document https://www.ljll.fr/~moussa/pdf/enseignements/cours_fluide_cinetique.pdf

Merci beaucoup!
